# Given $A^{-1}$ , find a matrix $C$ such that $ACA$ is a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 &2 &1\\ 0& 3& 1\\ 4& 1& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Find a matric $C$ such that
$$ACA= 
\begin{pmatrix} 2& 1& 3\\ -1& 2 &2\\2 & 1& 4
\end{pmatrix}.$$

My attempt at this problem is finding $A$, since the inverse of $A^{-1}$ is $A$.But I am getting fractions and I am not sure how to find $C$. Please no answers with cofactors as we are not in that chapter yet. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ACA= \begin {bmatrix} 2 & 1 &3 \\ -1& 2 &2\\ 2& 1& 4\\\end{bmatrix}$

$CA= A^{-1}\begin {bmatrix} 2 & 1 &3 \\ -1& 2 &2\\ 2& 1& 4\\\end{bmatrix}$

$C= A^{-1}\begin {bmatrix} 2 & 1 &3 \\ -1& 2 &2\\ 2& 1& 4\\\end{bmatrix}A^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $ACA=B$  and $A$ is invertible ( i.e. there exists $A^{-1}$ such that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$), than

$C=ICI=A^{-1}ACAA^{-1}=A^{-1}BA^{-1}$